# Is there an analogue exercise to deadlift for picking up objects at a distance?

Tags: deadlifts, barbell

Sometimes in life, it is just requirement to pick up things which are far away and we can't really get close to the object for picking it up. What exercises are there to train for such situations?

Comment: Like what for example?

Answer (score 2):

Atlas stone lifts, sandbag lifts/cleans/carries, and Zercher-grip squats and deadlifts all come to mind. The physical culture of strongman training is where to find experts in this topic.